preventing Tikz's \fill from spilling below the x-axis
I'm trying to \fill the area between two functions in a region bounded by a figure's x-axis, but I'm flummoxed by how to prevent some of the \fill from spilling down below the axis. Here's an image of the problem,

and here's my code:
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[usenames]{color}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\definecolor{burnt}{RGB}{191,87,0}\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[xscale=10,yscale=6]
% axes
\draw [thick] (0.15,1)--(0.15,0.2);
\draw [thick] (0.15,0.2)--(1.15,0.2);
\node [above] at (0.15,1) {\small{$\overline{d}$}};
\node [right] at (1.15,0.2) {\small{$x$}};
% values
\node [below] at (0.15,0.2) {\small{$\phantom{\overline{c}_B}0\phantom{\overline{c}_B}$}};
\node [below] at (1.15,0.2) {\small{$\phantom{\overline{c}_B}1\phantom{\overline{c}_B}$}};
% lines
\node [below] at (0.33,0.2) {\small{$\phantom{\overline{c}_B}x_A\phantom{\overline{c}_B}$}};
\node [below] at (0.62,0.2) {\small{$x_B(0)$}};
\node [below] at (0.92,0.2) {\small{$x_B(\overline{c}_B)$}};
\draw [black,thick,domain=0.33:0.442] plot (\x, {-0.028/(\x-0.47)}); %a
\draw [black,thick,domain=0.54:0.62] plot (\x, {0.02/(\x-0.52)}); %blo
\draw [black,thick,domain=0.625:0.64111] plot (\x, {0.008/(0.25-2*(\x-0.52))}); %xast
\draw [black,thick,domain=0.84:0.92] plot (\x, {0.02/(\x-0.82)}); %bhi
% fill
\fill [burnt,domain=0.54:0.64111,variable=\x] plot (\x, {0.02/(\x-0.52)})--plot (\x, {0.008/(0.25-2*(\x-0.52))});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}

I've tried putting plot (/x, {0.2}) in between the two functions in the \fill command to fix a lower bound, as I would connecting points with \fill, but it only makes things worse. (I've also tried giving \fill a path between the relevant two points (0.62,0.2)--(0.625,0.2), and that's no help either.)
What am I missing?

Welcome to TeX.SX! Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for TeX.SX users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

Very minimal change is to use separate domains for two paths: \fill [burnt,variable=\x] plot[domain=0.54:0.62] (\x, {0.02/(\x-0.52)})--plot[domain=0.625:0.64111] (\x, {0.008/(0.25-2*(\x-0.52))});. But I'd better switch to pgfplots for such graphs.

Fantastic! Thank you so much, @SergeiGolovan.
